# GFI Leviton LB115-DS Testing at outlet with GCFI Tester

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, gfci

We're purchasing a new construction home and had an inspection done on it. The inspector flagged that the bathrooms were not GFCI protected. The builder is telling me that the panel is using leviton GFI breakers (https://www.leviton.com/en/products/lb115-df) in the panel in the garage. I think they are model LB115-DF. I bought my own GFCI tester (https://www.lowes.com/pd/Southwire-Analog-120-Volt-Test-Meter/1000970284) and tried using that on the receptacles. The circuits in the kitchen trip when I press the test button on the GFCI tester. In the bathrooms, when I press the test button nothing happens. The power stays on to the outlet. The garage and laundry room receptacles trip when I use the GCFI tester and press the test button. All of the resets are on the panel in the garage.

Is the GFCI Tester I'm using not the right tool to test GFI Circuit Breakers? Also, all the breakers in the panel look the same. So I would assume all the circuits in the house have that protection, but it seems like only the Kitchen, Laundry, and Garage trip with the tester.

Is there a potential wiring issue here? Do I need a different tool for testing this type of breaker to be confident its working right?

Comment: What happens when you use the TEST button on the breakers in question?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please [edit] your post to include clear, focused pictures of your panel, particularly of the breakers labeled for the bathrooms or other locations you're concerned about. (Click the "sun & mountains" icon above the text entry box & upload the pics there. They'll get posted for you.) Someone will be able to identify whether they're GFCI breakers very quickly from that.

Comment: Well, let's see here, the home inspector told you the bathrooms were not GFCI protected, and your tester confirmed that. That the breakers all look the same means you probably have AFCI breakers not GFCI or dual function breakers.  The builder needs to install GFCI outlets at the head of each bathroom circuit.

Comment: @George Anderson the op said all the same, and other rooms work. looks like an open ground to me and some one did not test, I test 100% of GFCI’s because our local inspectors do. I would rather catch a simple open than have an inspector find it.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Comment: So the final result was builder said there was a GFCI breaker in the panel. There wasn't one. So they installed a GFCI outlet in the bathroom that is closest to the panel which is connected to the remaining ones. That solved it.

Answer (score 1):

If this were a old home I would say no problem if the tester on the breaker worked. But since this is a new home get the contractor to connect the grounds.

The GFCI can and will function correctly as it doesn’t use the ground at all in its circuitry. The GFCI circuits detect a difference in the current on the hot and neutral if there is an imbalance they will trip.

Your circuit tester places a resistance of ~15k from the ground to the hot causing a properly wired receptacle on a GFCI breaker to trip.
If both your’s and the inspectors testers did not work some one was lazy and did not connect the ground and that is why the GFCI test is not tripping the circuit.

It can be a simple case of a wire coming loose but make the contractor fix it it will probably be a simple fix.